# Mysql Tunning Server with 64 GB Ram consuming 50% of CPU

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a dedicated server with 64 GB Ram running Centos 7 with 4 cores and 8 threads.

I host there some wordpress websites with not much traffic.

In total around 20 websites and only 2-3 of them getting 1000 visitors /day

My cpu load is around 200% - 400% and 90% of this usage is taken by MySQL

Can someone help me please? I have days researching and trying to optimize but impossible with my knowledge.

my.cnf is as follows:

```
    [mysql]

# CLIENT #
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /home/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
local-infile                   = 0
performance_schema             = ON

# GENERAL #
user                           = mysql
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB
socket                         = /home/mysql/mysql.sock
pid-file                       = /home/mysql/mysql.pid

# MyISAM #
key-buffer-size                = 32M
myisam-recover-options         = FORCE,BACKUP

# SAFETY #
max-allowed-packet             = 16M
max-connect-errors             = 1000000

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /home/mysql/

# BINARY LOGGING #
log-bin                        = /home/mysql/mysql-bin
expire-logs-days               = 2
sync-binlog                    = 1

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp_table_size                 = 256M
max_heap_table_size            = 256M
query_cache_type               = 1
query_cache_size               = 128M
query_cache_limit              = 2M
max_connections                = 500
thread_cache_size              = 50
open-files-limit               = 65535
table_definition_cache         = 4096
table_open_cache               = 4096


# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = O_DIRECT
innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb-log-file-size           = 5G
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-buffer-pool-size        = 40G
innodb-buffer-pool-instances   = 40
join_buffer_size               = 4M


# LOGGING #
log-error                      = /home/mysql/mysql-error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 1
slow-query-log                 = 0
slow-query-log-file            = /home/mysql/mysql-slow.log
```

Comment: Too little information, too broad of a problem. My guess is bad queries/table design. Can you show your schema/some queries?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf-ini [mysqld] section

```
max_connect_errors=10  # from 1000000 to limit hacker/cracker pw guessing
#join_buffer_size=4M  # lead to allow DEFAULT to work for you
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8  # from 40  will serve you better than 40
innodb_lru_scan_depth=128  # from 1024 default
log_warnings=2  # for additional info in error log when aborted_connection
```

refer to refman for innodb_lru_scan_depth description to know why 8 is better than 40.  Your CPU workload every SECOND will be minimized.

Providing the additional information requested will allow more in depth analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try them now. I found what was causing all this. From my apache logs I sow a lot of requests to xmlrpc.php files of all wordpress installations I have. I blocked IPs making the requests and deleted/renamed all xmlrpc files.